# Retrieve the data from parse query and displaying in html template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am using parse for my app.I created tables in parse and i want to retrieve that particular tables data and displaying that data in my html template.

i'm creating a controller for getting the data from query but it does'nt show in my html template.controller code is follow

**Controller**

```
var object = Parse.Object.extend("TableForData");
var query = new Parse.Query(object);
var user = new Parse.User();

Parse.User.logIn(id, password, {
    success: function(user) {

        //retrieve data from parse table 
        query.equalTo("id", id);
        query.find({
            success: function(results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var object = results[i];
                    console.log(object.id + ' - ' + object.get("Name") + " " + );

                    $scope.name = object.get("Name");
                    console.log($scope.name); //this print correctly

                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }

        });

        $state.go('main.home');
        $scope.currentUser = user;
        $scope.$apply();

    },
    error: function(user, error) {
        // The login failed. Check error to see why.
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```

but ***$scope.name*** does'nt print in my html

```
    <body ng-controller="appCtrl">
      <div>
         <label>{{name}}</label>
     </div>
   </body>
```

Comment: Did you bind the contoller in to html?

Comment: yes i bind controller in my html

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this :

```
$timeout(function(){
  $scope.name= object.get("Name");
});
```

I think callback from query function might not be in Angular context.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing state with

```
$state.go('main.home');
```

You need to use service to share data between states.